# sql add number to sum the value from database

Tags: php, sql

Right now the value from the table is 1 and I want to add 5 so the final result would be 6.

The update always gets 5 so how can i just add 5 to the current number from the table?

```
$amount = 5

$sql = "UPDATE `table_projects` SET `package1`= $amount WHERE `id`='$userid'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will simply need to add `package` column on the right side of the operator `=` to add the `$amount` to itself.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table_projects` 
        SET `package1`= `package1` + " . (int)$amount . " 
        WHERE `id` = '$userid'";
```

**Notes:**

- I have added explicit typecasting to `(int)` on `$amount`. If it is going to be decimal/float value, you can use `(float)` instead.
- Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- If you are not going to use Prepared Statements, and if the `id` ($user_id) is integer value.

I would do typecasting on it as well

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table_projects` 
        SET `package1`= `package1` + " . (int)$amount . " 
        WHERE `id` = '" . (int)$userid . "'";
```

Comment: this needs to be `package1` or `package`?

Comment: @DigiNetEvents fixed the typo. It is `package1`